# bottom up dynamic programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic

I was trying to write a dynamic programming that counts the number of ways in which the road can be paved by using stones that are 2, 3, 5 meters. When I put 2, it gave me an error and starting from 2 to 20, it was supposed to give an output of

> 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 8, 14, 16, 27, 36, 51, 77, 103, 155, 216, 309,
>   448

My code gives this result when I start the input from 3. Did I misunderstand something here?

```
def waysRoad(n):
    if n<0:
        return 0

    dp = [0] * (n+1)
    dp[0] = 1
    dp[1] = 0
    for i in range(2, n):
        sum = 0
        if i >=2:
            sum += dp[i-2]

        if i >=3:
            sum += dp[i-3]
        if i >=5:
            sum += dp[i-5]
        dp[i] = sum
    return dp[i]
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer Those are `ifs'` and not `if-else-ifs'`

Comment: Thanks @vivek_23 -- not enough coffee yet.

Comment: @MarkMeyer never mind, it happens. Coffee always works. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill `n-th` list entry, you need to use loop limit `n+1`:

```
for i in range(2, n + 1):
```

also it is worth to change return to

```
return dp[n]
```